# Porting processor-intensive app to Android - limit devices?

Tags: android, ios

I have a rather processor-intensive app that I'll be releasing shortly for iOS.  The iPhone 3GS, 4, and iPad hardware can handle the app fine, but earlier iPhones and early-generation iPod touches don't perform well enough to execute the app.  In the Apple App Store, I'll be able to limit the devices the app can be installed on my requiring the devices to be armv7 -- that way, I won't have to worry about disappointed users with earlier devices complaining because they installed it and it doesn't perform well or correctly.

My question:  If I were to go through the effort of writing the app for Android, do the marketplaces (or the apps themselves?) have a similar way of requiring a certain amount of performance ability?  I'd like to avoid having an app out there performing badly on older devices that weren't meant to be able to handle it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are able to set criteria for the app. I'm not sure if processor speed is one of the criteria, but you could certainly just develop for android 2.3 or 2.2 and that way, only higher powered phones would run the app, as they would have the later OS's and would therfore be able to see the app in the marketplace.

Comment: How do you set the criteria?  Links?  Are you sure there aren't any underpowered 2.2 devices?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on Android version as there are many devices not so powerful equipped with newish Android versions. Didn't find a proper solution either but checking [Filtering for technical reasons](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html) left me wondering if claiming your application used/provided live wallpaper filtered many of the slower machines out. Problem is that it might be a requirement for your application at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set some criteria in the Google Play store (here is their documentation on filters: http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) but there is no explicit performance ability to filter.

I don't think that Google page covers 100% of the filters, as I've seen devices specifically excluded (my Nexus 7 tablet on the Super Hexagon game) as well as some programs filtering by ARM instruction version number (although perhaps this is part of the SDK level).

The most user-friendly way to do this would be to have a free trial version, then when the app starts, simply run a benchmark and explain whether the program would perform well or not.